# Where to download Spring Roo 1.2.4 runtime?

Tags: eclipse, spring-roo, eclipse-juno, spring-tool-suite

I'm running Eclipse Juno 4.2 (upgraded from Indigo 3.7), with the Spring Tool Suite tools installed.  A while ago I had installed Spring Roo 1.2.2.RELEASE, and configured the Roo plugin to point to the 1.2.2.RELEASE runtime.

I would now like to upgrade to Spring 1.2.4.RELEASE, but cannot find the runtime anywhere.  I've looked on the Spring site, but cannot seem to find a download link to it anywhere.

So a few questions:

1) Is the runtime still required as a separate download and do I still need to configure Eclipse to point to it separately?

2) Where can I download the runtime from?

3) Why do I need the separate runtime?  Why is STS/Eclipse not smart enough to use the Roo artifact that is included in my maven project?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I still don't why I need the separate runtime to configure Eclipse, however, I did finally find a download link for the latest ROO packages: http://docs.spring.io/downloads/nightly/release-download.php?project=ROO

Comment: Damn... why did they do that ?