# spring roo windows installation "Could not find or load main class"

Tags: java, windows, spring, maven, installation

I'am trying to install roo spring under Windows 7-64 bit and get the following error when I run "roo.bat" (from any folder):

"**Error: Could not find or load main class org.springframework.roo.bootstrap.Main**"

The following PATH variable are added to my system variables:

**JAVA_HOME** -> `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45`

**MAVEN** -> `C:\roo-stuff\apache-maven-3.1.1\bin`

**ROO_HOME** -> `C:\roo-stuff\roo-source\bootstrap\src\main\bin`

**ROO** -> `C:\roo-stuff\roo-source\bootstrap\`

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found the solution by downloading again spring-roo from here:

http://docs.spring.io/downloads/nightly/release-download.php?project=ROO

By the way I found the link on this stackoverflow question:

[Where to download Spring Roo 1.2.4 runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19390892/where-to-download-spring-roo-1-2-4-runtime)

I hope this can help someone.

cheers